# Xcode 6 not deploying on iPhone 6

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, iphone-6

When I press *Run* on my Xcode 6.0.1 (latest version at this time), the build succeeds, Xcode logs:

> -AppName- is currently running on -DeviceName-

But nothing happens on my device.

Answer (score 0):

You must add your new device to your provisioning profile from the [Apple Dev Portal](http://developer.apple.com), *Devices > Add* - use iTunes to get the UDID - then *Provisioning Profiles > Select your PP > Add your new device > Download and click it*.

Indeed, current Xcode version does not display an error message relative to signing identity.